# How to dump SpaCy model outputs in jsonl format when using `spacy project run evaluate`

Tags: spacy

I am working on an NER task using Spacy, and I am looking to see the output of my model on examples that it is failing on. So far, I've been using the --displacy-path option (https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate) to print out html parses my results. This is helpful, but I want outputs formatted the same way that my evaluation input data is so I can more easily compare the two.

Current output:

```
<figure style="margin-bottom: 6rem">
<div class="entities" style="line-height: 2.5; direction: ltr">The patient 's shortness of breath was also considered possibly related to a coronary event and she was admitted for rule out 
<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    myocardial infarction
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">HYPOTHETICAL</span>
</mark>
 .</div>
</figure>
```

Desired output:

```
{"text": "The patient 's shortness of breath was also considered possibly related to a coronary event and she was admitted for rule out myocardial infarction", "spans": [[100, 110, "TAG"]]
```